# create-react-app typescript global.d.ts file doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I've got my `global.d.ts` file in `src` folder like this

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    config: {
      url: string;
    };
  }
}
```

Then somewhere in my components do

```
window.config = 'x';
```

And `ts` shows this error

```
Error:(10, 22) TS2339: Property 'config' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

create-react-app is used for this app.

```
"react-scripts": "3.0.1",
"typescript": "3.5.3"
```

This is how `tsconfig.json` looks like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Provided your `.d.ts` file doesn't import or export anything, you can omit the `declare global` block.

You will need to make sure this file is either in an `@types` directory, or that you have configured your `typeRoots` to include the directory for your type declarations e.g.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/",
      "./custom/path/to/declarations/"
    ]
  }
}
```

Some more info about this can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types).

Answer (score 29):

A simpler approach would be to export an empty object from your `global.d.ts`, like so:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    config: {
      url: string;
    };
  }
}

// Adding this exports the declaration file which Typescript/CRA can now pickup:
export {}
```

Comment: Very nice zero-config approach.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, except in my case I want to declare my global types in a `@types` folder in my top-level directory.

I solved the error by adding the root to my `tsconfig.json`'s `include` paths:

```json
// in tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
  },
  "include": [
    // ...
    "."   // adds root as an include path
  ]

}
```