# How to globally redefine the FormData TypeScript interface in React Native?

Tags: javascript, typescript

When doing a simple `append` with FormData in React Native like this...

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image-data', {
  uri: '/awesome-chat-app/ImagePicker/abb9-a435046e971c.jpg',
  name: 'image001.jpg',
  type: 'image/jpeg',
});
```

TypeScript complains...

> <sub>Argument of type '{ uri: any; name: string; type: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'uri' does not exist in type 'Blob'.ts(2345)</sub>

So I was able to redefine FormData like this... ([hat tip](http://www.masteringreactjs.com/2018/04/11/one-neat-typescript-trick-that-saved-the-day/))

```js
interface FormDataValue {
  uri: string;
  name: string;
  type: string;
}

interface FormData {
  append(name: string, value: string | Blob | FormDataValue, fileName?: string): void;
  delete(name: string): void;
  get(name: string): FormDataEntryValue | null;
  getAll(name: string): FormDataEntryValue[];
  has(name: string): boolean;
  set(name: string, value: string | Blob | FormDataValue, fileName?: string): void;
}

declare let FormData: {
  prototype: FormData;
  new (form?: HTMLFormElement): FormData;
};

interface FormData {
  entries(): IterableIterator<[string, string | File]>;
  keys(): IterableIterator<string>;
  values(): IterableIterator<string | File>;
  [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<string | File>;
}
```

This works great directly within the file I'm doing the `append`.

How do I define it globally in the project so it overrides all uses of FormData?

Comment: Maybe try to put this in a file like `formData.d.ts`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe there's something that needs to be added to get it to work that way?

Comment: Not answering the question directly, but here's an alternative approach that got rid of the TypeScript error for me: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77685337/4350421

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a global [ambient module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) to extend the `FormData` interface defined in [`lib.dom.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/29becf05012bfa7ba20d50b0d16813971e46b8a6/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5657-L5665) via [interface merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces):

```
declare global {
  interface FormDataValue {
    uri: string;
    name: string;
    type: string;
  }

  interface FormData {
    append(name: string, value: FormDataValue, fileName?: string): void;
    set(name: string, value: FormDataValue, fileName?: string): void;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I created a `typings` folder at the top level of my project and then created a `formdata.d.ts` file with the code you posted but still get the error. Sorry, I'm super niave in this area and need more details.

Comment: Wherever you use it, you'll need a `/// <reference path="formdata.d.ts"/>` since you put it in `typings`.

Comment: How do I correctly define it globally so it doesn't need to be imported?

Comment: @GollyJer reference it at the entry point of your project (most likely guess is it's called `app.tsx`) and you won't need to import it anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Upon more reading I created a `global.d.ts` file and put your code in there. This seems to work with no import required and without the `declare global {}` portion. Interface merging is cool!  Thanks again, Jeremy.

Comment: it wasn't working until adding a `export {};` in the bottom in my react native expo project. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62011156/6414615

Comment: @types/react-native already includes a RN-compatible definition of FormData: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/e84e47bed9da60b6c65e3bbcf3c12ff82ccafead/types/react-native/v0.65/globals.d.ts#L65 so if you have @types/react-native as a dependency it seems like it shouldn't be necessary to write your own .d.ts file for it. Anyone know what's up with that?

Comment: to answer my own question: i found this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43990 which basically says that if you depend on any library that has `/// <reference lib="dom" />` in it, that will pull in TypeScript's DOM typedefs, even if you specify a `"lib"` value in your tsconfig that should exclude them. If you can work with the owners of that library to get that line removed, TS should look only at the react-native definition, and then you don't need to write your own .d.ts!