# How to append local images to FormData, from Expo v48 onwards?

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

When using Expo v47 and its corresponding React Native and TypeScript version, FormData.append had the following typing:

```
FormData.append(name: string, value: any): void
```

The images could be appended with this sort of code:

```
const image = {
  uri: x.uri,
  name: x.name,
  size: x.size,
  type: 'image/jpeg',
}

const formDataBody = new FormData()
formDataBody.append('data', image)
```

Now in Expo v48 and v49, and their corresponding RN and TS versions, the typing has changed to the following:

```
FormData.append(name: string, value: string | Blob): void
```

I've tried this sort of code, but I'm receiving Network Error while trying to POST the FormData:

```
try {
  base64String = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(image.uri, { encoding: 'base64' })
} catch (error: any) {
  // ...
}

const binaryData = decode(base64String)

//create a Uint8Array to represent the binary data
const buffer = new Uint8Array(binaryData.length)
for (let i = 0; i < binaryData.length; i++) {
  buffer[i] = binaryData.charCodeAt(i)
}

//create a File object from the binary data
const file = new File([binaryData], 'data', { type: 'image/jpeg' })

formDataBody.append('data', file)
```

I'm also aware, that modules such as react-native-fs could be used, but it gave me the following error:

```
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following did the trick:

```js
import FormData from "form-data";

//...

const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('image', {
  uri: imageUri,
  name: filename,
  type
});
```

I'm using Expo SDK version 49 and in my case, `form-data` came installed as a dependency of `@expo/cli`. You may have to install the library separately.