# Adding a custom property to an HTML attribute in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Is there a way to add a custom type to a react HTML element? I'm using React 16.13.1 with Create React App and Typescript 3.9.5. The only solution I have found is to either disable type checking, which is not ideal, or declare the react module interface at the top of every single component (as below). Is there a way to add this globally? Or a different solution?

```
declare module 'react' {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
        customAttribute?: any;
        // more attributes...
    }
}
```

I have tried adding it to a created index.d.ts file and adding to tsconfig.json `"compilerOptions": {"types":["./index.d.ts"]}` but I still get

`TS2322: Type '{ children: Element[]; customAttribute: string; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.   Property 'customAttribute' does not exist on type`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try to use declaration files? Add a `index.d.ts` in your project and the types should be available globally

Comment: Yes. This is what I was trying when I said I had created an `index.d.ts` file but that I was still getting the TS2322 error.

Comment: Having reviewed the docs on declarations I realised I was exporting and importing my declaration incorrectly. Thanks for your comment which confirmed declarations were the correct way forward.

Answer (score 4):

Adding an `index.d.ts` file and importing the interface in the component solved this.

```
// index.d.ts
import "react";

declare module 'react' {
    export interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
        customAttribute?: any;
    }
}
```

Either add this to any components which use the typing:

```
// component
import HTMLAttributes from "../index.d";

function MyComponent() {
   return <div customAttribute=""></div>
}
```

or add index.d.ts to the tsconfig

```
//tsconfig.json
"include": [ "path/to/index.d.ts" ]
```

Comment: it doesn't work  with the second way, I added the "include": [ "path/to/index.d.ts" ] to my tsconfig.json file, but it still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have all type declarations included by default, you could use `typeRoots` compiler option.

You simply have to add the following to your TS config file:

````
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types/",
      "./"
    ]
  }
}```

References:
1. [Create global.d.ts][1]
2. [Typescript typeRoots][2]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125019/create-react-app-typescript-global-d-ts-file-doesnt-work
  [2]: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots
````