# How to make Svelte aware of custom *.d.ts files?

Tags: typescript, svelte

I want to import some `*.txt` file as a string into a svelte component. The following typescript code raises no warning in VS Code:

```
// global.d.ts
declare module "*.txt" {
    const content: string;
    export default content;
}
```

```
// test.ts
import txt from "./test.txt";
```

However, if I try to import the same text file into a Svelte component (while `global.d.ts` still exists):

```
// Test.svelte
<script type="typescript">
    import txt from "./test.txt";
</script>
```

, VS Code will complain `Cannot find module './test.txt' or its corresponding type declarations. ts(2307)`. So how to properly tell Svelte about the declarations inside `global.d.ts`?

Comment: Does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57125019/create-react-app-typescript-global-d-ts-file-doesnt-work

Comment: How does your `tsconfig.json` look like?

Comment: Does it work using the `?raw` param with vite? https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets#importing-asset-as-string